# Pyqt Display data from mysql in tablewidget incomplete

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm newbie in PyQt,recently I want to use pyqt to do a data management system for athletes data.I create 50*3 blank `Item`.But when I delete data and then insert data, the data is not completely displayed on the interface.And when I add data，there is a mistake
`a=self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(col).text() 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

I use Qt designer to write UI program

```
 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s

    try:
        _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
            MainWindow.resize(841, 690)
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
            self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 661, 401))
            self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
            self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
            self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 240, 113, 20))
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
            self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
            self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 280, 113, 20))
            self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
            self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
            self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 320, 113, 20))
            self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 54, 16))
            self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
            self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 51, 20))
            self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
            self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
            self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 320, 54, 16))
            self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
            self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 240, 75, 23))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
            self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
            self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 280, 75, 23))
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
            self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
            self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 320, 75, 23))
            self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
            self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.tab)
            self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 611, 192))
            self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
            self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
            self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
            self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.QYolk = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.QYolk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 841, 23))
            self.QYolk.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("QYolk"))
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.QYolk)
            self.label.setBuddy(self.lineEdit)
            self.label_2.setBuddy(self.lineEdit_2)
            self.label_3.setBuddy(self.lineEdit_3)
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
            self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  name0", None))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name1", None))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name2", None))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "add", None))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "save", None))
            self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "delete", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name0", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name1", None))
            item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name2", None))
            __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
            self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "player1", None))
            self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "player2", None))
```

Here is my back-end program.I use `cellchange` to get the changed data.Is it a good idea?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui,QtSql
    import sys

    class StartQt4(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")  
            self.db.setHostName("localhost")
            self.db.setDatabaseName("test")   
            self.db.setUserName("root")
            self.db.setPassword("")
            self.q=QtSql.QSqlQuery()
            if (self.db.open()):
                self.showdata()
            else:
                print "failed"
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"), self.changedata)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.adddata)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.deldata)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.savedata)

        def adddata(self):
            name0 = str(self.lineEdit.text()) 
            name1 = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            name2 = str(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            self.q.exec_("insert into player values ('%s','%s','%s')" %(name0,name1,name2))
            #lastrow=self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            #self.tableWidget.insertRow(lastrow)
            self.showdata()

        def changedata(self,row,col):
            co=self.tableWidget.columnCount()
            row =self.tableWidget.currentRow()
            a= self.tableWidget.selectedItems()
            col=self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
            a=self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(col).text()
            if (col < (co-1)):
                b=self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(col+1).text()
                t=self.tableWidget.item(row, col+1).text()
            elif (col == (co-1)):
                b=self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(col-1).text()
                t=self.tableWidget.item(row, col-1).text()
            dt=self.tableWidget.currentItem().text()
            self.q.exec_("update qiu set %s = '%s' where %s = %s " %(a,dt,b,t))

        def savedata(self):
            self.q.exec_("insert into player1 select distinct * from player")

        def deldata(self):
            #self.tableWidget.clear()
            row=self.tableWidget.currentRow()
            print row
            a=self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0).text()
            x=self.tableWidget.item(row,0).text()
            self.q.exec_("delete from qiu where %s=%s" %(a,x))
            self.showdata()

        def  showdata(self):
            self.q.exec_("select * from qiu")
            col=self.tableWidget.columnCount()
            for i in range(0,self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                self.q.next()
                for j in range(col):
                    x=self.q.value(j).toString()
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(x))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = StartQt4()
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Appreciate very much

Comment: I'm sorry,something is worry.`qiu` is `player`.I forgot  change it.

Comment: I'm solve the problem display incomplete.I use `self.tableWidget.clearContents()` in `showdata()` to updata.But the error is still working .